# Correct implementation of abstract factory

Tags: design-patterns

I am practicing in understanding abstract factory pattern and made this pseudo code:

```
abstract class AbstractPlane
    function startEngine
    function fly
    function stopEngine

class AirPlane extends AbstractPlane
    function startEngine
        echo 'start ap'
    function fly
        echo 'fly ap'
    function stopEngine
        echo 'stop ap'


class JetPlane extends AbstractPlane
    function startEngine
        echo 'start jp'
    function fly
        echo 'fly jp'
    function stopEngine
        echo 'stop jp'


class GetOnPlaneAndGo
    static function fullFlight(AbstractPlane plane)
        plane->startEngine
        plane->fly
        plane->stopEngine
    static function onlyStart(AbstractPlane plane)
        plane->startEngine
    static function onlyStop(AbstractPlane plane)
        plane->stopEngine


GetOnPlaneAndGo::fullFlight(new AirPlane)
//OUTPUT
start ap
fly ap
stop ap 

GetOnPlaneAndGo::onlyStart(new AirPlane)
//OUTPUT
start ap

GetOnPlaneAndGo::onlyStop(new JetPlane)
//OUTPUT
stop jp
```

My question is: Is it correct as implementation? As I understood it solves the problem of creating entire product families without specifying their concrete class.
As per my understandings I have `families` which are the `AirPlane` and `JetPlane` classes with the common `AbstracPlane` abstraction. But in the end I am again passing the `AirPlane` or `JetPlain` instance. Did I understand it correct or I am missing something ?
Until now, I thought factory is just something like this:

```
interface Plane
    function startEngine
    function fly
    function stopEngine

class AirPlane implements Plane

class JetPlane implements Plane

class PlaneFactory
    static function create(Plane plane)


PlaneFactory::create(AirPlane)
```

Comment: Hi Again! This is the factory pattern in general, but not the _abstract factory pattern_. The latter is used when you want to have __factories__ that can be swapped out but still share a common interface. And although I say "interface", I don't necessarily mean a literal `interface`, although that is common these days.

Comment: Looking at this from a normal factor pattern, using an abstract class and/or interface really depends. I'll use an abstract base class if I have one or more methods that I want to reuse code for, otherwise I'll just have an interface. Actually, I almost always have an interface and an abstract class that implements it, even if it is empty to start with, because I know there's a good chance that someday I will need to add shared code. I type (hint) with the interface always, the base class is just an implementation detail that consuming code shouldn't be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give products to a factory. A factory gives products to you. Where does a factory get products? It creates them out of blueprints.

```
interface AbstractPlaneFactory
    abstract function create(String description) -> AbstractPlane

class CivilPlaneFactory implements AbstractPlaneFactory
    function create(String description) -> AbstractPlane:
       if description == "big": return new Boeing747;
       if description == "small": return new CRJ200;

class WarPlaneFactory implements AbstractPlaneFactory
    function create(String description) -> AbstractPlane:
       if description == "big": return new B2;
       if description == "small": return new F16;
```